# The syntax the my python programming has some syntax errors

Tags: python, if-statement

This is how the exercise wants the output to be:

```
Give name: Peter
The given name is wrong.

Give name: John
Give password: Monkeys?
The password is incorrect.

Give name: John
Give password: ABC123
Both inputs are correct!
```

This is the code that I've written:

```
print("Give name:");
name = input();
if name == "John":
    print(name);
else: 
    print("The given name is wrong.");

print("Give password:");
password = input();
if password != "ABC123":
    print("The password is incorrect.");
else:
    print("Both inputs are correct!");
```

But the console prints out this:

```
Give name:
Peter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ohjelma.py", line 9, in 
    password = input();
The given name is wrong.
Give password:
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: How are you supplying input to the program? The EOFError could only come from non-console input.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your program will proceed regardless of whether your first `if` statement. You could flip your first `if` condition and then nest your password validation within the 2nd one:

```
print("Give name:")
name = input()
if name != "John": # This prevents your program from proceeding to the password part
    print("The given name is wrong.")
else: 
    print(name)

    print("Give password:")
    password = input()
    if password != "ABC123":
        print("The password is incorrect.")
    else:
        print("Both inputs are correct!")
```

P.S. You don't really need `;` in python, newlines and tabs work just fine and are in fact the suggested way of coding in python